# Explode Textarea each line in list item

Tags: php, foreach, explode

I am trying to get each new line of textarea as a list item with explode and foreach. I have tried \n, \n\r, \r\n and PHP_EOL but nothing works. Here is my function

```
function dt_explode_list($option,$explode_key,$ul_class) {

    $tacs = explode($explode_key, get_option($option));

    echo '<ul class="'.$ul_class.'">';

    foreach ($tacs as $tac) {

        echo '<li>'.$tac.'</li>';   

    }

    echo '</ul>';

}
```

Calling with this

```
<?php dt_explode_list('dt_condition_apply','\n','tick-list'); ?>
```

Comment: Try `"\n"` instead of `'\n'`.

Comment: You guyz are amazing...voted.. thanks a lot

Comment: Or just completely anal.  But thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New lines need to be in double quotes

```
<?php dt_explode_list('dt_condition_apply',"\n",'tick-list'); ?>
```

See "Double Quoted" http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: You all guyz are amazing.. just in a second I got solid answer. Love you all :) I have voted so will select your answer in few min once system allows.. Thanks again